# Closed expression for a $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \binom{n+i}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Find a closed expression of a following sum ($n,m \in N$):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \binom{n+i}{n}$$

Tried to use Pascal Identity but sum continues to grow with more complex subsums:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\binom{n+i}{n}=m\binom{n+1}{n}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}(m-i)\binom{n+i}{n-1}$$

Comment: Nice question! Can you define n? Is n defined to be any natural number?

Comment: @ktm5124 Thanks! Yes, n is a natural number

Comment: You can use the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) to evaluate this sum.

Comment: Mathematica calculation shows that the answer is $\frac{(m+1) \binom{m+n+1}{n}}{n+1}-1$